# How to integrate ReactJS application with Wagtail API. Steps to follow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wagtail, web-frontend, wagtail-apiv2

I am trying the write application in ReactJS and backend will be using Wagtail API.
I am trying to find out what all steps/what all configuration needs to be done on front end side as well on backend to integrate ReactJS with the Wagtail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter which backend you are using. You just need to call the services from your API in the React.

Small example:

File **index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from "./App";

export class ReactApp {
    static renderService(props, element) {
        ReactDOM.render(<App {...props}/>, element);
    }
}

window.ReactApp = ReactApp;
```

File **App.js**

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.PureComponent {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: null,
            inProgress: false
        }
    }

    async fetchData(url) {
        return await fetch(url)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({data}))
            .finally((e) => {
                this.setState({inProgress: false})
            });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchData(this.props.url);
    }


    render() {
        const {data, inProgress} = this.state;

        return (
            <div className="app">
                {
                    !inProgress && data &&
                    (
                        <div className="app__list">
                            {
                                data.map(item => <span className="app__list-item">{item.title}</span>)
                            }
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Then build your js code with webpack with index.js entry point and call it in your html

```
<div id="app"></div>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="build.js"></script>
<script>
    ReactApp. renderService({url: 'https://yourApiUrl'}, document.getElementById('app'));
</script>
```